# Remove first two blocks based on delimiter from multiline string

Tags: javascript

I can't find a precise answer for my problem. This is string to clean up:

```
2012/04/21 21:48:33 76C00790 CE 49 AC FD 37 EB 58 05 11 31 9F 8B 36 38 59 44
2012/04/21 21:48:34 76C00790 E9 6F 24 88 AB C8 18 63 FA 1E A8 1C 6A DB D2 A7
2012/04/21 21:48:34 76C00790 BB 94 85 3D F7 AE 9E 9A DB 21 06 D7 BF 02 3A EB
2012/04/21 21:48:34 76C00790 1D 37 56 DA 6D 03 1E 10 3E F8 F8 EC 23 0B 63 62
2012/04/21 21:48:35 76C00790 49 29 B4 A7 4B 16 F5 94 73 89 4C 33 88 1E AC FB
2012/04/21 21:48:35 76C00790 DC A3 B5 D2
```

I have to paste the above string and clean it with the `onkeyup` event in a textarea field, to this:

```
CE 49 AC FD 37 EB 58 05 11 31 9F 8B 36 38 59 44
E9 6F 24 88 AB C8 18 63 FA 1E A8 1C 6A DB D2 A7
BB 94 85 3D F7 AE 9E 9A DB 21 06 D7 BF 02 3A EB
1D 37 56 DA 6D 03 1E 10 3E F8 F8 EC 23 0B 63 62
49 29 B4 A7 4B 16 F5 94 73 89 4C 33 88 1E AC FB
DC A3 B5 D2
```

The first block on each new line is always date, second is always time, but the third block can have a different length.

So I think a reasonable delimiter would be a space, but how can I remove the first 3 blocks from every line and leave the rest?

**EDIT**

Thank you all for help!!
So, this is working example (tested in latest FF):

```
<html>
<head>
<script language="javascript">
<!--
function clean(input) {
 input.value = input.value.split("\n").map(function(entry) {
  return entry.replace(/^\d+\/\d+\/\d+ \d+:\d+:\d+ [A-F0-9]+ /, "");
 }).join("\n");
}
-->
</script>
</head>
<body>
 <textarea id="f" cols="80" rows="7"  onkeyup="javascript:clean(this);"></textarea>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: is this one string or array of strings ?

Comment: Seems your string have line breaks so you could use `/n` as delimiter to get each line in an array. Then just `substring` the first three blocks

Comment: could you edit your post defining the exact variable?

Comment: This is one string :) Let say, copied and pasted from clipboard to a textarea field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ooh! This is a perfect case for `String.split`, `Array.map`, and `Array.join`. I do this kind of stuff all the time:

```
data = data.split("\n").map(function(entry) {
  return entry.replace(/^\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2} [A-F0-9]+ /, "");
}).join("\n");
```

- `String.split` will split the string into an array based on a substring or regex (for us, `\n`)
- `Array.map` will run a function over each element in the array, returning a new array of the return values of the function
- `Array.join` will join an array with a string (in our case, `\n`)

<s>EDIT: You could probably just use `entry.substr(29)` instead of that regex, as well.</s> *false: the question specifically states that the third block to get rid of is of a variable length.*

DOUBLE EDIT: In your case, you could probably just use a straight regex, instead, as other people have shown. If you need to do anything more complex though (case conversions, sanitisation, etc), the `.split().map().join()` dance will be easier, I think.

TRIPLE EDIT: I've put together [a comparison](http://jsperf.com/string-split-and-replacement) of the performance of the top two answers here. Draw any conclusion you like from it.

Comment: OP says third line will have different length.

Comment: wth ? if he is gonna split it. it is better to get them using substring(29) using the fixed index '29' of the first wanted character ! it is always the same and that is way faster than replacing with regex, considering you already split it, split + regex = too much processes.

Comment: @CME64 - do you have numbers to back up your "too much processes" claim? I think you'll find that JavaScript engines will surprise you with what they are/aren't fast at. Also, your assumption is incorrect - the first character of the desired text isn't always going to be at the same offset. I made that same mistake with the first revision of my answer.

Comment: yes split looks for the delimiter process = n, regex also looks for a parameter to replace which is = 2n processes, your bigOh = 2n^2 = n^2 while you could reduce it a little by using a regex only = 2n, but if you split it and used substring , the substring = n => O(n^2)

Comment: @CME64 I'd love to see some actual solid measurements of that. I've been surprised over and over by what is fast and what isn't in various JavaScript engines.

Comment: from what I see the index of the first desired character is always the same considering there's a data and a time and a microseconds with the same digits number in each line

Comment: @DannyBeckett I know of jsperf (great tool!), but I'm not the one claiming any specific performance characteristics, so it's not my responsibility to prove the performance either way. EDIT: I'd love to be shown the error of my ways, if one of you fine gentlemen feels it necessary to do so.

Comment: are you saying that you are convinced that x = x+y ?

Comment: @deoxxa I'm just explaining how it could be improved, I don't mean any offence and you seem angry. when you cool down comeback to discuss things if you care about knowing the right thing.

Comment: @CME64 my apologies - 'tis not anger but rather enthusiasm. I'd honestly like to see a tangible demonstration of this performance issue, if only so that it's no longer a theoretical problem.

Comment: ok here is my reasoning,, split function is a loop over all n characters so checking characters = n operations, regex also is a loop of matching string algorithm probably the bigOh is n if no algorithms were used to enhance the performance .. n here = character count, m = number of strings, substring operation = 1 per string , total substring operations = m

Comment: split+regex => bigOh = n*(mn*m) = n*n = n^2,, split+substring => n*m,, regex => n

Comment: @CME64 you are correct! See [this jsperf entry](http://jsperf.com/string-split-and-replacement) for some proof. The gap isn't as wide as you seem to suggest, however. EDIT: a small change to the regex seems to have tipped it in favour of my solution.

Comment: I would like to compare all the three solutions, let me figure out how to use this tool, it is cool :)

Comment: this actually differ with huge data, this is a small sample, the difference could be small.

Comment: Thanks all for very fast answer! This solution works flawesly!

Comment: @deoxxa here is regex vs regex+split http://jsperf.com/speedtestregex and here is regex+split vs split+substring http://jsperf.com/splitandregex .. from these tests I discovered that regex is almost n log n not n or n^2 => that makes split+regex = (n^2)*log(n) and split+substring = n*m and regex = n*log(n)

Comment: @deoxxa I think my expectation for regex is wrong, the big oh of a normal replace function = n*k where k = length of match string, in regex it can take different forms so it has to test against all possible forms of the match that can extend to unknown. but replace itself could be using horsepool algorithm (the simplest matching algo) which has a best case of O(n) and worst O(n*k) [worse than n log n as seen from the results of the tests] here is the latest test http://jsperf.com/regex-vs-nonregex .

Answer (score 2):

Here's a non-RegEx solution:

```
var str = "2012/04/21 21:48:33 76C00790 CE 49 AC FD 37 EB 58 05 11 31 9F 8B 36 38 59 44\n2012/04/21 21:48:34 76C00790 E9 6F 24 88 AB C8 18 63 FA 1E A8 1C 6A DB D2 A7";

var str = str.split("\n");      // Split the string into an array on newlines
for(var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    str[i] = str[i].split(" "); // Split the string into an array on spaces
    str[i].splice(0, 3);        // Remove the first 3 blocks
    str[i] = str[i].join(" ");  // Join the array into a string with spaces

    alert(str[i]);              // CE 49 AC FD 37 EB 58 05 11 31 9F 8B 36 38 59 44
}
```

Here's [a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/XcxLX/1/) on JSFiddle.

If you want to keep the `76C00790` block too, change `3` to `2` in the `splice`.

---

Here's a shorter version, thanks to @bozdoz:

```
var str = "2012/04/21 21:48:33 76C00790 CE 49 AC FD 37 EB 58 05 11 31 9F 8B 36 38 59 44\n2012/04/21 21:48:34 76C00790 E9 6F 24 88 AB C8 18 63 FA 1E A8 1C 6A DB D2 A7";

var str = str.split("\n");
for(var i = 0; i < str.length; i++)
    alert(str[i].split(' ').splice(3).join(' '));
```

Comment: I think avoiding regex is probably a good idea.  Though your choice in variable names is questionable :). +1

Comment: @bozdoz I only used one variable, `str`, as in "string".

Comment: Okay then, your choice in not making a new name in the for loop.  Using `str[i]` as often as you are is a little misleading.

Comment: Or, why not chain the functions: `alert(str[i].split(' ').splice(3).join(' '))`

Comment: @bozdoz That doesn't do the same thing. Try it in JSFiddle.

Comment: @bozdoz Well I'll be. I chained the `split` and `splice` together, which gave a different result (still contained the date and time). It seems removing the `0, ` from the `splice` (as you did) fixes that. Good job!

Comment: Thanks buddy.  Good job yourself.  You should get the answer, but you might need to supply a way for OP to put the string back together, doing a join('\n') on the `str` array. :)

Comment: You might want to take a look at [this jsperf](http://jsperf.com/string-split-and-replacement) and explain why you're avoiding regexes.

Comment: @deoxxa Nice! I didn't expect that! Using bozdoz's one-liner, it's a little faster: http://jsperf.com/string-split-and-replacement/2

Comment: @DannyBeckett that could be the tagline for JavaScript - "I didn't expect that!", lol.

Comment: Mine performs better ;) http://jsperf.com/string-split-and-replacement/3 (your year regex is `\d{2}`, but should be `\d{4}`); I fixed it on jsperf.

Comment: A `substring` would probably work better on my version, after the split on `\n`.

Answer (score 1):

Do a regular expression split:

```
var arr = str.split(/\d{4}\/\d{2}\/\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2} .*? /g);
arr.shift(); //get rid of the first empty match
```

The regular expression checks for date: yyyy/mm/dd, then 2 digits : 2 digits : 2 digits, then any characters until a space. The `g` flag means that the regular expression searches globally (keeps searching the string even after the first match).

`arr` is now an array of each line.  To put it into a text box, you can convert it back to a multiline string with `arr.join('\n')`.

Answer (score 0):

Considering it is one string, use this RegEx:

```
str.replace( /\d{4}\/.{24}/g ,"");
```

Here's [a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/CME64/E2eHd/3/) on JSFiddle.

Answer (score 0):

```
myTextArea.value.replace(/(^|\n)\S+ \S+ \S+ /g, "$1")
```